# How to use an Array to search and delete folders in VBScript

Tags: vbscript

Just started using VBScript to automate some task on a server.
How can i utilize an Array in VBScript to search and delete certain folders?

Comment: Why do you need an array? Do you have a solution in search of a problem?

Comment: I have a number of folders that need to be deleted. Normally i the IF statement to check if the folders exists. Can it be done with the usage of Array's

Comment: What have you tried so far?, can you show some code then we might be able to help.

Answer (score 2):

Arrays are perfect for instances where you want to follow the [DRY prinicple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

For this task I would use a simple 1 dimensional array to list all of the folder locations you wish to process, something like this;

```
Dim folders, items, item

folders = Array( _
              "c:\folder1\subfolder1" _
            , "c:\folder2" _
            , "f:\folder1\subfolder1\subfolder1" _
          )

'Check we have a valid array
If IsArray(folders) Then    
  items = UBound(folders)
  For item = 0 to items
    'Call the function that will do the work
    Call DoTask(folders(item))
  Next
End If
```

The example assumes the processing is done by `DoTask()` function *(this can be any function you like)* which takes the folder as an input argument.

#### `For` or `For Each`?

As [MC ND](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2861476/mc-nd) has [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32948035/how-to-use-an-array-to-search-and-delete-folders-in-vbscript#comment53724296_32948802) you can use `For Each` as well the difference is negligible but worth pointing out. Here is an example using `For Each`.

```
Dim folders, folder

folders = Array( _
              "c:\folder1\subfolder1" _
            , "c:\folder2" _
            , "f:\folder1\subfolder1\subfolder1" _
          )

'Check we have a valid array
If IsArray(folders) Then
  For Each folder In folders
    'Call the function that will do the work
    Call DoTask(folder)
  Next
End If
```

---

So much for [spoon feeding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32948802/692942)

The `DoTask()` sub procedure would look something like this for the requested task.

```
Sub DoTask(folder)
  Dim fso

  Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  If fso.FolderExists(folder) Then
    Call fso.DeleteFolder(folder, True)
  End If
  Set fso = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Option Explicit

Dim aFolders
    aFolders = Array( "x:\folder1", "x:\folder2", "x:\folder3" ) 

Dim strFolder
    With WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
        For Each strFolder In aFolders 
            If .FolderExists(strFolder) Then 
                .DeleteFolder strFolder, True
            End If
        Next 
    End With
```

Comment: I think there is a difference between helping the OP come to a conclusion and just dishing it out for them. The approach I posted was designed to help them think about breaking the task down as I'm assuming they know how to delete a folder already (see [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32948035/how-to-use-an-array-to-search-and-delete-folders-in-vbscript#comment53721047_32948035)). Admittedly could have used a `For Each` but is there much difference? Also not a big fan of answers that don't provide any explanation, pointless in terms of SO imo.

Comment: Can't say I'm a big fan of [Hungarian notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation) in any code even script langauges, but that's my personal preference.

Comment: @Lankymart, Thank you. I think the same, but I also think that to iterate over an array executing an operation for each element is a *simple* task that must not be made more complicated than it should. So my decission was to include a *"minimal"*, *"clear"* (or not) code sample that shows *a way it can be done* and nothing more. I use Hungarian notation (and I agree than I don't follow the standard) when I think it clarifies something, as the fact that the `For Each` will retrieve each of the strings (directories) stored inside the array, not the index of the element being processed.

Comment: Well your certainly right about the *"nothing more"* bit of that sentence. See [How do I write a good answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

This project on SourceForge does lots of VBScript folder creation and deletion that you might get some inspiration from.
http://sourceforge.net/projects/simple-gtd/